# WPF MVVM Insert object via text boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, insert

I am trying to insert an object into the database using the MVVM pattern via textboxes. The actual problem is getting the object into the ViewModel in the first place. My idea was to add the NewCustomer, of the Customer type, in the ViewModel, and then bind the textboxes to the appropriate properties. Here's what it looks like:

XAML:

```
<Label Content="First Name:" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,0,325,227"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewCustomer.FirstName}"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,31,322,227"/>
<Label Content="Last Name:" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,74,325,158"/>
<TextBox  Text="{Binding NewCustomer.LastName}" Margin="10,110,325,148" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<Label Content="Bank Balance:" Margin="10,148,325,81" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewCustomer.BankBalance}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,179,322,81"/>
<Label Content="About me:" Margin="10,215,325,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewCustomer.AboutMe}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,246,322,10"/>
<Button Margin="255,113,67,141" Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Grid.Column="1">
```

ViewModel (the important parts):

```
private Customer _newCustomer;
public Customer NewCustomer
{
    get { return _newCustomer; }
    set
    {
        _newCustomer = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("NewCustomer");
    }
}
/.../
public void Add(object C)
{

    db.Customers.Add(NewCustomer);
    db.SaveChanges();
    LoadCustomers();

}

public RelayCommand AddCommand { get; set; }
#endregion
```

But for some reason the NewCustomer property is always null (checked via debugging).

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is null because no one created it,

Use this,

```
private Customer _newCustomer = new Customer();
```

Values should be bound correctly after

Or another way, in ViewModel constructor do init

```
NewCusomer = new Customer();
```